# Suggestion: style the kbd tag

Tags: discussion, design

Currently the `<kbd>` tag looks like this:

[image: default KBD tag]

This is the default look on Stack Exchange, styled to resemble a keyboard key.

However, I understand that different sites can have different styles. For instance, on [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) the tag looks like this:

[image: Gaming.SE KBD tag]

I suggest styling the tag so that it looks like a WP keyboard button. The following CSS seems to give a pretty good result:

```
kbd {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #474747;
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1.4;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Thoughts? Any other design ideas for when the site graduates from beta?

Comment: +1 Looks cool! :)

Answer (score 7):

Normally, a site's design wouldn't be changed [until it has graduated](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).

A quick glance at [our page on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) shows we need to work on the volume of questions being asked, and answered. The stats there also imply that we could do with more avid users (which is also tied to how often people vote) - so get asking, voting and answering :)

Comment: Ah, didn't know beta sites can't change designs, thanks for the info. Let this remain on the backburner for when we graduate, then. And yes, I agree we need to have more people asking more questions. I've been keeping an eye on the site stats myself. Hopefully once official rollout of 8.1 starts, people will have more questions.

Comment: One thing I forgot in my answer was that I totally agree that this would be a good idea; as well as following Windows Phone design for other things -- it'd be great if we could have a pivot type control to switch between newest/frequent/votes/active/unanswered, etc. I'd tagged with [tag:design] which should catch the designer's eye when we get close enough to graduation...

Comment: @Indrek You've serendipitously stumbled onto one of the [7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). :) You might want to expand your original post to solicit additional design ideas.